# What should be a community wiki post?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

[This link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/community-wiki) provides very less details actually.

**My views:**

- Some time i **see some posts brings discussion and sometime they are just get closed because they are too broad to give answer but they could be beneficial for the community**. I can remember some but not able to find them.Maybe linked them later on.

  **Can't we give a wiki-answer so that anybody can give there 2 cents to make it better.That would be beneficial for questioner as well as for community?**
- With that i see very rare posts which are posted as community-wiki.

  **Should we not encourage the newbies to post there answer as wiki if there are not clear but want to share there experience?**

**Questions:**
So basically i am asking for

1. your thoughts on my views above,
2. basically the different scenarios where one should post answer as wiki,
3. why questions can not be asked as community-wiki post??

Comment: Now i'm thinking that this question is going to be flagged for "Too broad to answer" ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your benefit, this is a Community Wiki answer. :)

First, it's important to remember that *anyone with sufficient reputation can edit someone else's answer to a question*, provided of course that they do no harm to the answer.

Ours is a relatively *new and young community* where we only have 9 "trusted users" and 6 who have sufficient reputation to have "moderator privileges". So in that sense, gaining reputation is still quite important to the benefit of our community.

Further, old questions can always be edited as the platform changes with new releases, allowing them to be updated with the latest information as appropriate by anyone.

There is no reason *not* to have community wiki questions and answers. It's more a case of someone choosing to start them on more generic topics that don't tend to be release sensitive. There are several subjects that would be well suited to wikis. Some of the following topics would be especially suitable:

- `Web Services`
- `Test Classes`
- `Triggers`
- `PDFs`
- `Batch`
- `Schedulables`
- `Queueables`

Comment: Nice. The reason "We are young community" for having less wiki answers is really reasonable.

Comment: I don't see a way to ask community-wiki questions.I have read somewhere that only moderator can change questions to community-wiki?? I have updated question with more style to have clear focus.

Comment: If you ask a self-answer question, you can mark the answer for community wiki. But I believe you'd still get points for the question.

Comment: @crmprogdev I have self-answered in the past, and I do generally mark those as wiki, because they're generally useful and I want to encourage them to be updated when needed. I also use wiki when I want to answer a question but may not have all the details, or answering a question that's very likely to have its answer change in the foreseeable future, or even when answering a borderline open-ended question to encourage all the good info to coalesce into a single answer that benefits the community. I agree it's a useful tool.

Comment: We are only 6 as of this last week. :)

Comment: Interesting... @sfdcfox I posted this as a WIKI answer and everyone is commenting below it! Seems we need practice with utilizing and contributing to wikis. LOL!

Comment: To be fair, you structured a lot of your sentences in a personal way (using "I" a lot, for example). I edited it to sound more community authored, maybe that's part of it?

Comment: @AdrianLarson You did a great job of editing the post. I can only say that's how I'm used to expressing my opinions. What you say could very well be the case. I really don't know. It was the first time I've either started a WIKI or contributed to one. As I said, "we need practice" with WIKI's. I was including myself in the "we". I'm no exception when it comes to needing to learn how to use them. ;)

Comment: Where is the do no harm stuff defined?  I added an edit to one of @AdrianLarson 's posts today, and someone provided a reject because it was "promoting something else and defacing".  Adrian and David Schach ultimately approved it, but I was curious if I crossed a line?  (I added the list of SimpleDateFormat items to his answer helping someone with mm vs MM mistake).  Did I provide benefit or confusion and defacement?

Comment: @drakored Sounds like a fine meta question in its own right. I think the content was somewhat irrelevant (I included the relevant excerpt already), but it looked like you put a lot of work into it and it didn't hurt either, so I approved it.

Comment: Also, if you look at just the markdown, it does look like somewhat of a red flag. I had to look at the rendered output to understand what's going on.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I was just searching for that exact thing at the moment heh.  Makes sense, maybe I need to read up on what the purpose of posts are long term.  My understanding (minimal, probably off) was that questions were supposed to be like long standing answers for others later on (potentially exceeding the original slightly).  I'll go read up and then post a separate question so I don't deviate this thread.  Thanks!

Comment: Yea, seems SE is no fan of tables.  Had to alter the table to text, which makes things a bit odd.